# Proof for "A simple connected graph has n-1 edges iff it is a tree " without induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am trying to prove that a simple connected graph with n nodes has n-1 edges iff it is a tree.

I could prove it using induction but I was wondering if there is any other method.

As soon we add one more edge to a simple connected graph with n-1 edges it forms a cycle but I was not able to prove that.

Comment: Do you mean a simple, connected graph?

Comment: What definition of tree are you using ?  There are a couple so the proof depends on that...

Comment: A tree is a simple connected graph of without any cycles.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the minimum spanning tree (MST) of $n-1$ edges (a simple connected graph has one) from a graph with $n$ edges (or more), you still have one edge.

Between the vertices of this edge, a path should be in the MST, forming a cycle in the original graph.